# How to get the path to your saved image in django

Tags: python, django

I created a form model using the code below

```
class TrainImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TrainImage
        fields = (
            'image',
        )

    def customSave(self):
        lv = self.save(commit=False)
        lv.save()
        return lv.image.name
```

And this is how I saved uploaded image. But any time I try to retrieve the image, I get a "FileNotFoundError"

```
def testnetwork(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TrainImageForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            filename = str(form.customSave())
            img_array = imageio.imread("media/train_images/" + filename,as_gray=True)
            img_data = 255.0 - img_array.reshape(784)
            img_data = (img_data/255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01
            global n
            output = n.query(img_data)
            label = numpy.argmax(output)
```

But when I input the path of the file manually (in the imageio.imread), it works without any error. Please how do I go about this

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.path is the method you want if your storage backend implements it. the name is just the name.